# How to wire Minivector control relay for Honeywell Wifi Thermostat to control 240v baseboard heater

Tags: thermostat, baseboard, wifi

new here, and just a "homeowner electrician". When I bought the house there was a low voltage thermostat controlling a 240v Cadet baseboard heater. Upon investigation, there is a Minivector Delay Controller downstairs that is running the baseboard. There are only two wires running to the thermostat from the controller. One leg on the baseboard is hot all the time. If I twist the two thermostat wires together, after a delay the other leg becomes hot and the baseboard heats up. Here is my dilemma... I am trying to install a Honeywell Wifi thermostat and I am not sure how to plug in one or both of the thermostat wires to get the second leg to become hot. I have bought a "C" wire transformer and have the thermostat powered up, just not sure about getting the Minivector to activate that second leg. I have plugged each one of the two wires into the "W" connection, individually, on the thermostat, waited and tested. Either time, only the one leg had power.
Sorry if I left out any I fo needed as I am trying to be as specific as possible. Thank you for any help you would be able to provide me.

Comment: Can you post photos of this delay controller/control relay? And what model of thermostat are you trying to use?

Comment: Hold on. What voltage does the existing setup use?  Do you know? Does the existing setup have a transformer (yes it does). Can you tap that?  What are you doing with the other legacy wire? Leaving it floating in air?  Is there a 3rd wire in the legacy cable?